# Vue js : Multiple instance VS Single instance but template from HTML, what is the best practice for performances

Tags: javascript, performance, vue.js, optimization

I have seen some questions in stackoverflow about that subject, but they never really mentioned performances.

Let's say that I have HTML page with a list of Shop,
this HTML list is generated by the server *in* the page HTML.

I would like for each Shop HTML "block" to display a Vue JS `<Calendar />` component

HTML :

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="shop">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
           <div class="component-placeholder" data-shop-id="x"></div>
    ....
  </div>
  <div class="shop">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
           <div class="component-placeholder" data-shop-id="x"></div>
    ....
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

For JS there is 2 possibility.

Option 1 :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.component-placeholder').forEach((item) => {
  const shopId = item.getAttribute('data-shop-id');
  new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(Calendar, {
      props: {
        shopId,
      },
    }),
  }).$mount(item);
});
```

Option 2 :

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('.list');
new Vue({
  el: elem,
  components: {
    Calendar
  },
});

// for this I would replace the component-placeholder with <Calendar shop-id="x" /> in the HTML
```

My question is, what is the best practice when focusing on performance ?

If the list has 30 Shop, `Option 1` would create 30 instance of Vue living together,
but `Option 2` would also need to add and create all the HTML elements inside its shadow DOM when the component is first loading no ?

Comment: u can just import calendar in your template Shop which can be a component that takes props

Comment: thanks, but that is not really the question, I'm asking. I don't want to create a <Shop> component (for several reasons).
and the question stay the same, what if there is 30 <Shop>, what solution impact the most the performance

Comment: you get these 30 blocks from the backend, so you can use v-for and just put a calendar in it

Comment: v-for on the `<dist class="shop">` right ? since I get the RAW html from the server I don't have a props with the data I can loop into.
But once again, my question is about performance and not how to display the page content.

Comment: I don't expect a serious difference in performance for this case, so stick to the solution that makes more sense. Which is to create1 app instance instead of 30. You can always check the performance yourself in devtools